# MariaDB 10.1 Docker crash InnoDB

Tags: mysql, docker, mariadb

I have an error with Docker and MariaDB 10.1.

I must have MariaDB 10.1 version for my old project, so I will not upgrade MariaDB.

I followed official MariaDB 10.1 GitHub to make Dockerfile. It compiles but doesn't start.

Here my error :

```
mariadb       | 2020-02-06 14:09:39+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 1:10.1.44+maria-1~bionic started.
mariadb       | 2020-02-06 14:09:40+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
mariadb       | 2020-02-06 14:09:40+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 1:10.1.44+maria-1~bionic started.
mariadb       | 2020-02-06 14:09:40 140685262989312 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 10.1.44-MariaDB-1~bionic) starting as process 1 ...
mariadb       | 2020-02-06 14:09:40 140685262989312 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
mariadb       | 2020-02-06 14:09:40 140685262989312 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
mariadb       | 2020-02-06 14:09:40 140685262989312 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
mariadb       | 2020-02-06 14:09:40 140685262989312 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
mariadb       | 2020-02-06 14:09:40 140685262989312 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
mariadb       | 2020-02-06 14:09:40 140685262989312 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
mariadb       | 2020-02-06 14:09:40 140685262989312 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE crc32 instructions
mariadb       | 2020-02-06 14:09:40 140685262989312 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 256.0M
mariadb       | 2020-02-06 14:09:40 140685262989312 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
mariadb       | 2020-02-06 14:09:40 140685262989312 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
mariadb       | InnoDB: No valid checkpoint found.
mariadb       | InnoDB: A downgrade from MariaDB 10.2.2 or later is not supported.
mariadb       | InnoDB: If this error appears when you are creating an InnoDB database,
mariadb       | InnoDB: the problem may be that during an earlier attempt you managed
mariadb       | InnoDB: to create the InnoDB data files, but log file creation failed.
mariadb       | InnoDB: If that is the case, please refer to
mariadb       | InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/error-creating-innodb.html
mariadb       | 2020-02-06 14:09:40 140685262989312 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
mariadb       | 2020-02-06 14:09:40 140685262989312 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
mariadb       | 2020-02-06 14:09:40 140685262989312 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
mariadb       | 2020-02-06 14:09:40 140685262989312 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
mariadb       | 2020-02-06 14:09:40 140685262989312 [ERROR] Aborting
```

How can I ignore this error ?

Thank you for reading me